# Getting a < 75 Watt charger for a macbook pro due to flight constraints

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power

My MacBook Pro with Retina display (Mid 2012) charger has a rating of 85 Watts.

I want to use it on a flight from Sydney to Los Angeles. (24 hours). (Airbus A380-800).

You can plug in an AC adapter - but they have [the following rule](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/inflight-communications/global/en#jump2):

> The PC power is configured to provide a maximum of output of 75 watts. If the limit is exceeded by a user, which is possible on new version PCs the power to the user will be interrupted and can only be reset on the ground.

This means if I plug in my charger - I'll lock out my power supply for the remainder of the 24 hour flight.

Can I get a lower wattage power adapter for my MacBook Pro?

Comment: You can safely use the low watt adapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple sells a [60W MagSafe2 Power Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD565LL/A/apple-60w-magsafe-2-power-adaptermacbook-pro-with-13-inch-retina-display) for US$79.00 for the MacBook Pro with 13-inch Retina display. They also sell a [60W MagSafe Power Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC461LL/A/apple-60w-magsafe-power-adapter-for-macbook-and-13-inch-macbook-pro).

Comment: My experience is that the 60W adapters will maintain an existing amount of charge in an MBP but, *warning*, they will not charge a totally dead battery.

Comment: New security regulations may be in effect on flights to and from the antipodes. J G should make sure to keep the battery charged before boarding the flight in Sydney should the laptop need to be booted at the security checkpoint, and then charged up for the return flight.

Comment: the 60w charger will work great. It will charge slower than the 85w power supply, but under light/moderate workloads the 60w charger will be fine.